# Draw Hexahedral Mesh Efficiently Using OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I try to implement some kind of mesh visualiser for Finite-Element-Programms in Python. For this, I want to use PyQtGraph. I was able to implement a first version of the Visualiser which is able to plot a 3D mesh as shown in the picture below.

[image: Example Mesh]

However, operations such as zooming and rotating take quite long for larger meshes. I plot the mesh using GLLinePlotItem. I guess the performance is poor due to the huge amount of lines generated with large meshes.
I am wondering whether there is an efficient way to display my mesh rather than using the GLLineItem. I had a look at GLMeshItem, however, this represents the mesh using triangles and not quads.

Here is my code for the visualiser:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import sys

class Visualizer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.w = gl.GLViewWidget()
        self.w.opts['distance'] = 400
        self.w.setWindowTitle('Mesh Visualiser')
        self.w.setGeometry(0, 110, 1920, 1080)
        self.w.show()

    def start(self):
        if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
            QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()

    def add_line_item(self,pts,width):
        item = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=pts, width=width, antialias=False)
        self.w.addItem(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = Visualizer()

    # Code which generates the GlLineItems is called here ...
    # ...

    v.start()
```

I also have a code which is called at the position of the comment in the code and generates the GlLinePlotItems from the nodes of the mesh. The GlLinePlotItems are added to the GlViewWidget using the `add_line_item() method.

Comment: The doco says that PyQtGraph is using the old fixed function pipeline (classic OpenGL, versions 1 and 2) which is often slow and buggy and modern 3D hardware. Switching to triangles instead of quads might help.
Beyond that, you will probably have to dig into the internals of GLLinePlotItem etc to determine if you are making the most efficient use. For example, it's almost always faster to draw 10,000 quads in one go instead of 10,000 individual quads